# C/C++ Initialise double with hex

Tags: c++, double, hex, uint64

I want to initialise a double with a hex constant.

```
double dbl = 0xFEDCBA9876543212;
printf("dbl: %llX\n", (uint64_t)dbl);
```

I would expect to see as the output:

```
dbl: FEDCBA9876543212
```

But I am getting:

```
dbl: FEDCBA9876543000
```

Why is this and why are the last 3 bytes being dropped off?

Comment: Doing so could cost billions of dollars! Seen that, been there ...

Comment: Being itself a 64-bit datatype, `double` can't represent the full precision of a 64-bit integer value, since it also needs space for the exponent part.

Comment: Punch "what every computer scientist should know about floating point" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I would be nice, if you would give the actual link here: ["what every computer scientist should know about floating point"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: You are assiging an integer value to a `double` - my guess is that you actually want to assign the bitwise equivalent value as a `double`, in which case you will need to use `reinterpret_cast` as Zak suggests.

Comment: I am actually writing some code which involves splitting up a double (64 bits) into 2 x uint32_t variables for transmission over a particular network type.  For my unit tests, I want to set all 64 bits of the double to a known value, check each uint32_t, recombine the 2 x uint32_t and check the resulting double against the double at the start.

Comment: You can, as I wrote below, specify the exact bit patterns of a floating point in C with hex float literals. But otherwise, I'd be more concerned about the value actually being correct the other end - it's fairly obvious for nearly all float values (assuming IEEE-754) when you start mixing bytes or words up - except for zero, getting just a few bits wrong typically gives a completely different number [I'd also check that the bytes received the other end before conversion back to double is correct - e.g. if you expect 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, ... then you can check that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just wanting to do a memcpy style transaction you can try:

```
uint64_t x = 0xFEDCBA9876543212;
double dbl = *reinterpret_cast<double *>(&x);
```

Also, your test may not be doing what you want:

**My test:**

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

int main (void) {
  // Move the underlying hex value through multiple types
  uint64_t x = 0xFEDCBA9876543212;
  double dbl = *reinterpret_cast<double *>(&x);
  uint64_t y = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t *>(&dbl);

  // Check integrity of the result
  printf("dbl: %llX\n", (uint64_t)dbl);  //your test
  printf("x: %llx\ny: %llx\n", x, y);  //my test

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
dbl: 8000000000000000
x: fedcba9876543212
y: fedcba9876543212
```

As you can see, the underlying binary value remains the same as it passes from `x` to `dbl` to `y`, even though your current test `printf("dbl: %llX\n", (uint64_t)dbl);` produces unexpected output.

Comment: How do I do the equivalent thing in C?

Comment: @Noah: `double dbl = *(double *)&x` and `uint64_t y = *(uint64_t *)&dbl`.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a 64-bit value to initialize a double, which only holds 53 significant bits. There's one bit of rounding, and the remaining bits are just lost.

Comment: It appears he has the hex representation of the double, and wants to store it in a double.

Comment: @rcgldr I don't see that implied anywhere in the question.

Comment: He specifically states what output he expected, the same 64 bit number that he assigned to the dbl.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know exactly the value of your double, then use the hex format of doubles,

```
0x1.01234567898abcp-12
```

and then print the number with `printf("%p", number);` once you have assembled the number at the other end. The number should match the input if you have the right number of digits.

Answer (score 1):

[`double` precision is 53 bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), that's why you are getting zeros on remaining positions.

Comment: No, not fixed. The bit I'm talking about is hidden and exists separately from the sign.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, you can also use unions

```
union
{
    long long _double_exact;
    double _double;
};
double_exact = 0xFEDCBA9876543212;
```